# How to use `AsRef` arguments?

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I am having a hard time trying to get `AsRef` to work in a clean way.

```rust
const DEFAULT: &str = "lib";

use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn extend(p: &Path, q: Option<&Path>) -> PathBuf {
    let q: &Path = q.unwrap_or(DEFAULT.as_ref());
    p.join(q)
}

// DOES NOT COMPILE
fn extend1<P: AsRef<Path>, Q: AsRef<Path>>(p: P, q: Option<Q>) -> PathBuf {
    let q: &Path = q.map(|x| x.as_ref()).unwrap_or(DEFAULT.as_ref());
    p.as_ref().join(q)
}

// DOES NOT COMPILE
fn extend2<P: AsRef<Path>, Q: AsRef<Path>>(p: P, q: Option<Q>) -> PathBuf {
    let q: &Path = match q {
        Some(x) => x.as_ref(),
        None => DEFAULT.as_ref(),
    };
    p.as_ref().join(q)
}

fn extend3<P: AsRef<Path>, Q: AsRef<Path>>(p: P, q: Option<Q>) -> PathBuf {
    match q {
        Some(x) => p.as_ref().join(x.as_ref()),
        None => p.as_ref().join(AsRef::<Path>::as_ref(DEFAULT)),
    }
}
```

The function `extend` works with `Path` references, but I want to generalize it to accept arguments of type `AsRef<Path>` in order to allow also string, for instance.

My first attempts, `extend1` and `extend2`, do not pass the borrow checker, which complains about the lifetime of `x` in both cases.

My third attempt, `extend3`, works, but has the obvious drawback of code duplication, which gets more severe as the function body grows.

What is the best solution in this circumstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Option::map` consumes the inner value (if there is one). So in the code `q.map(|x| x.as_ref())`, the closure takes `x` by value. You can check this by noting that `q.map(|x: &Q| x.as_ref())` gives a type error, while `q.map(|x: Q| x.as_ref())` does not (it still gives the lifetime error). That means that when you call `x.as_ref()`, a new reference to x is created, not related to any outside reference. This means that the reference is only valid inside the closure, but you want to use it in the rest of `extend1`.

What you want to do instead is have a borrow of `q` that's valid until the end of `extend1`. This borrow of `q` can be turned into a borrow of its contents (if any) using `Option::as_ref()` to convert `&Option<Q>` into `Option<&Q>` (simply using `q.as_ref()` will create the borrow of `q` you need). Then when you use map, the closure will take `&Q`, rather than `Q`. The lifetime of the reference will be the same as the external borrow of `q`, so it will last until the end of `extend1` (if needed).

```
const DEFAULT: &str = "lib";

use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn extend1<P: AsRef<Path>, Q: AsRef<Path>>(p: P, q: Option<Q>) -> PathBuf {
    let q: &Path = q.as_ref().map(|x| x.as_ref()).unwrap_or(DEFAULT.as_ref());
    p.as_ref().join(q)
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a18d68ae380978cdff340234d3d0cc3)

Since the arguments to your function are only ever used by reference, you may wish to only take them by reference. This is as easy as adding an ampersand to each argument.

```
const DEFAULT: &str = "lib";

use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn extend1<P: AsRef<Path>, Q: AsRef<Path>>(p: &P, q: &Option<Q>) -> PathBuf {
    let q: &Path = q.as_ref().map(|x| x.as_ref()).unwrap_or(DEFAULT.as_ref());
    p.as_ref().join(q)
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da243126141e50e88e13893edd24e7e0)

or

```
const DEFAULT: &str = "lib";

use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn extend1<P: AsRef<Path>, Q: AsRef<Path>>(p: &P, q: Option<&Q>) -> PathBuf {
    let q: &Path = q.map(|x| x.as_ref()).unwrap_or(DEFAULT.as_ref());
    p.as_ref().join(q)
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d86c141e399c4e67bb280015d39661a)

Note that this last version doesn't need to call `q.as_ref()`, since `q` already has type `Option<&Q>`. This version most closely follows your original `extend` function.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it better. Still, I think I prefer the first implementation you gave to the second and third, because it is more general: it accepts also `Option<PathBuf>` and `Option<String>`.  What is your opinion about choosing among the three versions? It seems more similar to what [`Path::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join) does.

Comment: To me, the third option seems best since it's more explicit about the fact that it's cloning the paths (since it couldn't possibly reuse either of the arguments). It's still just as general, since it's easy to borrow if needed at the call site (e.g. `extend1(&string, option_string.as_ref())`). Still, it's up to you. The consistency with `Path::join` is nice, though I'd probably expect a function with the name "extend" to take a mutable reference and change the original `Path` object (compare to the [`Extend` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Extend.html)).